# Защита приложения Андроид

Tags: android, google-play

Подскажите, вот скачал человек приложение с play вытащил apk и теперь может установить его на любое количество устройств, разместить в сети и т.д.

Существуют ли методы защиты? и вообще это какая дырка мне кажется.

Answer (score 3):

[Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html)  
С помощью этой штуки можно проверить лицензию конкретного пользователя на использование конкретного приложения(платного, или бесплатного), и решить, разрешать ему запуск, или нет... 
Но количество выложенных платных приложений, на пример на 4pda подтверждает тот факт, что почти любую защиту можно обойти.  
Я бы советовал делать какую-то авторизацию на сервере для защиты...

Comment: да по факту то любая защита взламывается :)

Comment: Если приложение оффлайн, то авторизация на сервере, это как бы совсем не то.
Похоже что пользователь может скачать платное приложение, а потом отменить транзакцию... Получается что писать приложения на Российский рынок с попыткой их монетизации это эпикфайл.

Comment: @Nub сами вы эпикфейл... Вы недооцениваете разработчиков Андроида. Любое, даже оффлайновое приложение может связаться с маркетом посредством специальной службы, которое предоставляется приложением Android Play/Market, которое всегда установлено в аппарате. Приложение связывается с сервером гугля и проверяет лицензию.

Comment: аналогично работает и любой другой маркет: Yandex Market, Amazon Market, Samsung Market и проч. Они (маркеты) осуществляют связь с серваком вендора, покупку, in-app billing, проверку лицензии и проч. лабуду.

Comment: 2Barmaley ну ну... расскажите мне как офлайновое приложение может с кем то связваться ;) видимо телепатически, мне такие методы разработки не доступны и если вы не уловили, то я разработчик под Андроид и эту проблему выявил после того как сделал одно приложение платным, до этого я как то не задумывался над тем как защитить приложение от копирования. Поэтому и возник этот топик.
Если вы считаете, что я не прав, то можете поподробнее рассказать о методах защиты, может я действительно чего то незнаю.

Comment: @Nub фигово изучали документацию :) У маркет приложения есть сервис к которому обращается ваша оффлайн аппа. Далее маркет сам связывается с сервером... Телепатия не причем :)

Answer (score 0):

Методы защиты есть, но они не работают. Из не сломанных на 4pda я помню только Poweramp (Возможно уже все изменилось). Лучше придумайте способ монетизации отличный от продажи.

Comment: PowerAmp уже очень давно взломали. Правда взлом "кривой", без танцев с бубнами никак...

Comment: реклама, как то раздражает людей, да и выхлопа особого нет... давай те обсудим методы монетизации ;)